# Error calling web method from jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I am calling a WebMethod from jQuery doing the following:

```
 function WebMethod(fn, paramArray, successFn, errorFn) {
    var paramList = {};
    if (paramArray.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i += 2) {
            paramList[paramArray[i]] = paramArray[i + 1];
        }
    }

    var params = $.toJSON(paramList);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../../PricingEngine/ContractView.aspx' + '/' + fn,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: params,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: successFn,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // Display a generic error for now.
            alert("AJAX Error!");
        }
    });
}


// Used returned object to populate every field
function updateTextFields(result) {
    //do some processing here
}

function failed(result) {
    alert('failed');

}

// EVENTS
// ------------------------------------------------------------

$(".editableField").keydown(function(e) {

    WebMethod('PriceContract',
                    [
                     'AQ', aq.val(),
                     'SOQ', soq.val()
                    ], updateTextFields, failed);

});
```

The JSON string after the .toJSON has been called:

> {"AQ":"140000","SOQ":"1169"}

**The C# method**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static ContractsListPricing PriceContract(string AQ, string SOQ)
{
    ContractsListPricing clp = new ContractsListPricing();

    clp.Aq = 1;
    clp.Soq = 2;

    return clp;
}
```

This is returning the following error:

> Invalid JSON: (Followed by the complete HTML of the current page).

Please take no notice of the logic in the C# as this isn't implemented yet. I am using the jquery-json plugin to parse the JSON.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive run a demo of your code and got it working fine. Have you checked that you have the ScriptModule Handler set correctly in your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

You're sure the exact url is '../../PricingEngine/ContractView.aspx' + '/' + fn ?

Because ContractView.aspx IS your current webpage

Comment: Yeah it points to the correct page, if I change it I get an error saying it cannot find it.

Comment: I never used WebMethod but it looks like you're pointing to the asp page instead of the webmethod.